# What variation of regular expressions is supported by an input pattern?

Tags: regex, html, html-input

What variation of regular expressions are supported by the `pattern` attribute of an HTML5 `<input>`? Is it POSIX ([BRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) or [ERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended)), [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), or something else? In particular I would like to know what meta characters, character classes, and subexpressions are supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The regular expression language is the same as JavaScript's.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input.

Or if you prefer:

> The pattern attribute specifies a regular expression against which the
>   control's value, or, when the multiple attribute applies and is set,
>   the control's values, are to be checked.
>
> If specified, the attribute's value must match the **JavaScript Pattern
>   production**. [ECMA262]
>
> If an input element has a pattern attribute specified, and the
>   attribute's value, when compiled as a **JavaScript regular expression**
>   with the global, ignoreCase, and multiline flags disabled (see ECMA262
>   Edition 5, sections 15.10.7.2 through 15.10.7.4), compiles
>   successfully, then the resulting regular expression is the element's
>   compiled pattern regular expression. If the element has no such
>   attribute, or if the value doesn't compile successfully, then the
>   element has no compiled pattern regular expression. [ECMA262]
>
> […]
>
> The compiled pattern regular expression, when matched against a string, must have its start anchored to the start of the string and its end anchored to the end of the string.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute.

Comment: +1. Notice however that in contrast to JavaScript's `test` function the pattern is *anchored* to the start and end of the string automatically.